# T-SQL converting string into float

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, type-conversion

In a stored procedure on my SQL Server, I am trying to convert values from a varchar column into a float format.
The values into the varchar column are numbers with a sign at the beginning and a '.' before decimals.

Examples: '+0000000000000044.09' or '-0000000000114995.61'

If I try this: *convert(float,mystring)*, it doesn't work.
I have:

> *Error converting data type varchar to float*

Is this kind of conversion possible?
Or is there another way to convert a string with a sign and a '.' into a float?

Comment: Both the examples will work.. Show proper samples which is failing

Comment: Show the code too. This works 
SELECT CAST('+0000000000000044.09' AS float)
SELECT CAST('-0000000000114995.61' AS float)

Comment: Your examples work for me. Are you sure it's not just a rogue value in your table causing the problem?

Comment: From SQL Server 2012 onwards, `TRY_CONVERT` is available to attempt the conversions without erroring out. You could extend the stored procedure to use this and `RAISERROR` an explicit message about the exact value that's failing.

Comment: Thank you all, trying to execute the query in a select statement I don't have any errors. I found an error when I tried to verify the query. Trying to use the TRY_CONVERT i found out that problem was a value which caused the converion failure.

Answer (score 1):

As your examples both work, I'd guess there's another value somewhere in your table that's causing the problem. In recent versions of SQL Server (2012 onwards), the [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) function can be useful for tracking down this kind of issue.

`TRY_CONVERT` will not throw an exception on a conversion failure, but instead return a NULL value, so you can figure out which values are causing the problem like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, your_column_name) IS NULL
```

If any rows are returned, those are the rows with problem values that can't be converted to FLOAT.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `CAST(mystring as float)` or `TRY_CONVERT(float,mystring)`.
Thuough convert(float,mystring) also should work fine. I would suggest checking your data.